# Sending a POST request to a Python Lambda function through API Gateway from HTML

Tags: python, api, post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function on AWS and it's written in Python 3.6
I also have my API deployed and the CORS enabled to all of my resources
When I test the POST from AWS API gateway it works fine and the same
Success I get when I try it from Postman but when I try it from
The html hosted in my S3 bucket it does not work! I try to make the post request like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/myapp',
  data: '{"fName":"jonas","lName": "Hoda", " Email":"abcd@zxy.net", "Age": 45, "Hight": 190, "Income": 120000}', 
  success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

But I keep getting the same response:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app.my-real-domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

What else do I have to do? 
Do I need to edit something in my API or at my Python function?
Pleases help me fix this
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: It's saying that you don't appear to have CORS enabled. Did you redeploy the API after enabling CORS?

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes of course I re-deployed after enabling the CORS ...actually I re-deployed many time after and I check the headers every time to make sure the CORS are enabled and everything is OK but still the same error

Comment: Are you using Lambda Proxy integration?

Comment: @dashmug thanks for your response, and no I do not use Lambda Proxy integration

Comment: @AboJoTheGreat Great. In your mapping templates, make sure you return the correct CORS headers.

Comment: Sorry but how do I put the CORS headers in the mapping template? thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the solution!
First I tried all the ideas I got here and nothing worked
Actually most of them were already applied in my project
So I tried to see if the problem is in the API or is it in
The request so I disabled the Request Validator in the 
API-Gateway and suddenly it worked!
The post request went just fine with no errors and the lambda
At the back-end worked, stored the data at the Dynamo DB and
Returned the right response so I edited my Model schema at 
API-Gateway and removed the 'required' part and applied it again
And everything is OK now!
I do not know why this solved the issue specially that I reviewed 
The parameters tens of times and it's being passed using the right
Names and types ..
Anyway I just wanted to share this if anyone else has this problem
And thanks for anyone tried to help me...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Like you, I have been through most suggestions and had most already applied. I have an API rule set up in Cloudfront... Where is this request validator of which you speak? Can you remember?

Answer (score 0):

CORS doesn't seem to be setup on your resource.

There is a wizard on the console that helps you setup CORS on a resource. The documentation also has a detailed guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html on how to setup CORS.